# How to remove express sessions that are inactive?

Tags: node.js, express, passport.js, passport-local

Im using `express-session` and `passport-local` to authenticate my users and I want to be able to get currently online users.
Logging in works fine, session is created and storing user's Id and I can get all the current sessions.
But what if the user logout or just leave the page? The session is still there and when I get all sessions I will see this user even though he left the page and is no longer online.

My express-session code:

```
app.use(
  session({
    store: new (pgSession(session))(),
    secret: process.env.SESSION_SECRET,
    resave: false,
    saveUninitialized: false,
    cookie: {
      maxAge: 24 * 60 * 60 * 1000
    },
  })
);
```

So my question is if there is some sort of mechanism that removes inactive sessions and also what I should do to be sure that I have only active sessions in my store? (I would appriciate any longer article or answer on this topic)

Answer (score 1):

What you are looking for is `req.session.destroy()` which will remove the session from your database. You can integrate this method in your `/logout` route.

Example:

```js
router.get('/logout', (req, res, next) => {
  req.logout();
  req.session.destroy((err) => {
    if (err) return next(err);
    return res.redirect('/login');
  });
});
```

Comment: Yeah, I found it already. But what if user leaves the page? I don't destroy his session so he is still there

Comment: The maxAge can automatically handle expired sessions while allowing some flexibility for users to re-enter your site without re-logging in. If you want users to have to re-login every time they leave the website you could potentially add a `window.addEventListener("beforeunload", cb)` to the front-end that sends a message to trigger the logout and destroying the session.